# How Print results to Tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python script which create a frame and print statement which prints to the terminal. how can i print line 1 to Tkinter frame.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        print "line 1"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x600")
app = MainApp(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `print` goes to console, if you want it on the `tkinter` you will have to set up a label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Whatsthepoint has suggested you may have to use a Label. I have posted your modified code below.

```
import Tkinter as tk
class MainApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = tk.Label(parent, text = "line 1")
        self.label.pack()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x600")
app = MainApp(root)
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT -1** : Additional option if you want to display a text area (Not sure what u want exactly) instead of a label.

```
    self.text = tk.Text(parent)
    self.text.insert(tk.END, " line 1")
    self.text.pack()
```

**EDIT-2** To answer your question for displaying values from a list. please note that this is just a simple display of numbers from a list. You need to customize things as per your need.

```
     self.mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
     tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
     self.parent = parent
     for values in self.mylist:
         self.label = tk.Label(parent, text=values)
         self.label.pack()
```

Comment: But what if i have a loop, to print numbers from 1 to 10 @DineshKumar

Comment: @Sanchez Please check my updated answer. Note tht its just a simple way of displaying the number from a list in a loop.